# How to change the language to Arabic in pw.Table.fromTextArea in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the List<String> columnNames, and function shoppingTable() to return the values of the table that the user inputted it.

//**The problem:**

I made method for making pdf document from the internet, in the method I used `pw.Table.fromTextArray`, and I added `textDirection:pw.TextDirection.rtl` and `textAlign: pw.TextAlign.right`, but (**the problem:**) the texts letters in the table are intermittent. How I can make the text letters are not intermittent?

The code:

```
> `var table;
> 8 أعمدة
> final pw.Font txtFont =
> pw.Font.ttf(await rootBundle.load("assets/fonts/NotoNaskhArabic-Medium.ttf"));
> table = pw.Table.fromTextArray(
> headers: columnNames.map((e){
> String headerText =
> pw.Text(e,
> style: pw.TextStyle(font: txtFont),
> textAlign: pw.TextAlign.right,
> textDirection: pw.TextDirection.rtl).text.toPlainText();
> String text = "";
> for(int letterP= e.length-1;letterP>=0;letterP--){
> String a = headerText[letterP];
> text += a;
>         }
> headerText = pw.Text(text,
> style: pw.TextStyle(font: txtFont),
> textDirection: pw.TextDirection.rtl,
> textAlign: pw.TextAlign.right,
>             ).text.toPlainText();
> return headerText;
>       }).toList().reversed.toList(),
> data: shoppingTable(),
> cellAlignment: pw.Alignment.centerRight, // تحديد محاذاة النص إلى اليمين
> headerAlignment: pw.Alignment.centerRight, // تحديد محاذاة العناوين إلى اليمين
> cellStyle: pw.TextStyle(font: txtFont),
> headerStyle: pw.TextStyle(font: txtFont),
>     );
> `
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NK55.png) The application output

I want a method or a function or a property to add it to solve this problem: How to make the Arabic texts in pw.Table.fromTextArray are not intermittent like the above image?